# NSStatusItem doesn't work in fullscreen mode starting 10.13

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsstatusbar

Very simple application. When any other application is in fullscreen mode my apps system tray drop down menu doesn't show up. Other application like system time's drop down shows up properly.

**No app in fullscreen**

[image]

**Xcode app in full screen (icon is clicked but drop down is not shown)**

[image]

Here is my code ->

```
NSStatusItem *g;
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSStatusItem *statusItem = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];

    statusItem.menu = [[NSMenu alloc] init];
    NSMenuItem *test = [[NSMenuItem alloc] init];

    test.title = @"Just a test";
    [statusItem.menu addItem:test];


    NSImage *img = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.icns"];
    [img setSize:NSMakeSize(18.0, 18.0)];
    statusItem.image = img;
    g = statusItem;
}
```

Comment: hi @PnotNP, just a suggestion, may you forget retain for statusItem ? If its problem just 10.13, disregard the comment

Comment: @emrahkorkmaz I'm aware of retain and I'm sure its retained properly.

Comment: @PnotNP, did you find any solution for this?